# learning linux drivers

Tags: linux, driver, device-driver, linux-device-driver

I am learning now days programming drivers.

I am doing my learning  from this book [Linux Device Drivers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596005903)

But I am little bit lack of practice. Can you recommend me some simple projects that I can get started with.

Or some open source project that newbie can understand what is going on.

Additional examples and tutorials will be welcomed .

Thanks for help.

Comment: Just for the record, there is a free <a href="http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/">onlive version of the LDD3</a> book.

Comment: FYI, if you want to browse the Linux kernel sources, visit lxr.linux.no, the official Linux cross-reference site

Comment: See similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60763/learning-kernel-hacking-and-embedded-development-at-home/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Free software magazine has an article about that :

http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/drivers_linux?page=0%2C0

this tutorial is downloadable as PDF.

This article describes the programming of a USB driver for a home made multicolored light. I think its quite interesting :)

http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7353

For more "complete" drivers, I would look at the code of "serial" drivers (meaning driver for devices connected to a plain old serial port or USB port) because the data transfer between your computer and the device feels more natural.

Answer (score 1):

The given below link is very good to kickstart the linux device drivers learning:

http://www.linuxforu.com/tag/linux-device-drivers-series/page/2/

-Aditya-